# Highlight the connectors for one shape only

Tags: libreoffice-draw

In the diagram below it is not clear to which shapes the triangle is connected and which connectors belong to connections between the other shapes. Is it somehow possible to only select/highlight the triangle's connectors?

It would also be an option to select the triangle, it's connectors and all the shapes connected to the connectors, if that makes the solution easier. Other possibilities, e.g. hiding everything else would be acceptable as well.

Mainly I want to avoid switching to MS Visio, I'm open to any other alternatives, including other software.

**Note**: this is a simplified example, in the actual scenario the shape has a lot of connectors going out from the same point so moving doesn't really help and selecting them one by one would be too labour intensive.

[image]

Comment: Is it LibreOffice Draw? Try moving the triangle.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes, it's Draw, sorry. This is just a simplified example, in the actual scenario moving unfortunately doesn't help any more. And the shape has a lot of connectors going out from the same point so selecting them one by one would be too labour intensive.